concurrent.futures and Pandas DataFrame
I tried use multiprocessing to create 2 dataframes at the same time. The result of 2 functions are Pandas Dataframe. When I tried use 'concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor', but I can't extrat this Dataframes.
Code:
data_inicial_cdi = '02/01/1998'
data_inicial_selic = '04/01/2021'
data_final = date.today().strftime('%d/%m/%Y')

def taxa_CDI(*knargs):
    dt1 = data_inicial_cdi
    dt2 = data_final
    taxa_CDI = sgs.dataframe([4389], start=data_inicial_cdi, end=data_final)
    taxa_CDI.rename(columns = {4389: 'CDI_taxa'}, inplace=True)
    taxa_CDI.dropna(inplace=True)
    taxa_CDI['CDI_fator'] =  (1+taxa_CDI['CDI_taxa']/100) ** (1/252)
    taxa_CDI['CDI_acum'] =  np.cumprod(taxa_CDI['CDI_fator'] )
    taxa_CDI['Data'] = taxa_CDI.index
    total_registro_cdi = len(taxa_CDI)
    index_cdi = np.array(range(total_registro_cdi))
    taxa_CDI.set_index(index_cdi, inplace=True)

    return taxa_CDI

def taxa_Selic(*knargs):
    dt1 = data_inicial_selic
    dt2 = data_final
    taxa_Selic = sgs.dataframe([1178], start=data_inicial_selic, end=data_final)
    taxa_Selic.rename(columns={1178: 'Selic_taxa'}, inplace=True)
    taxa_Selic.dropna(inplace=True)
    taxa_Selic['Selic_fator'] = (1 + taxa_Selic['Selic_taxa'] / 100) ** (1 / 252)
    taxa_Selic['Selic_acum'] = np.cumprod(taxa_Selic['Selic_fator'])
    taxa_Selic['Data'] = taxa_Selic.index
    total_registro_selic = len(taxa_Selic)
    index_selic = np.array(range(total_registro_selic))
    taxa_Selic.set_index(index_selic, inplace=True)

    return taxa_Selic

if __name__ == '__main__':

    with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=2) as executor:
        cod1 = executor.submit(taxa_CDI(data_inicial_cdi, data_final))
        cod2 = executor.submit(taxa_Selic(data_inicial_selic, data_final))
        df_cdi = cod1.result()
        df_selic = cod2.result()
       print(cod1, cod2)

Is possible extrat this data frames?
Erro:
TypeError: 'DataFrame' object is not callable


Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a minimal reproducible example.

The concurrent futures API does not take a direct function call like this.
with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=2) as executor:
    cod1 = executor.submit(taxa_CDI(data_inicial_cdi, data_final))
#                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    cod2 = executor.submit(taxa_Selic(data_inicial_selic, data_final))
#                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

You need to rewrite it to match the method signature, which takes some function fn and then all the various parameters afterwards.
The reason why you get TypeError is because is that you're making an explicit call to your function  – taxa_CDI(data_inicial_cdi, data_final) – and then passing the result, a DataFrame as the function to be executed on submission. What the TypeError message means is, in essence, that a DataFrame is not a function (ie not not "callable").
Rewrite instead as the following, passing the function you want as the first parameter and then the arguments to that function as *args.
with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=2) as executor:
    cod1 = executor.submit(taxa_CDI, data_inicial_cdi, data_final)
    cod2 = executor.submit(taxa_Selic, data_inicial_selic, data_final)

